# Map List of Tuples to New Column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
In [76]: df
Out[76]: 
          a         b  c
0 -0.685397  0.845976  w
1  0.065439  2.642052  x
2 -0.220823 -2.040816  y
3 -1.331632 -0.162705  z
```

Suppose I have a list of tuples:

```
In [78]: tp
Out[78]: [('z', 0.25), ('y', 0.33), ('x', 0.5), ('w', 0.75)]
```

I would like to map `tp` do `df` such that the the second element in each tuple lands in a new column that corresponds with the row matching the first element in each tuple.

The end result would look like this:

```
In [87]: df2
Out[87]: 
          a         b  c   new
0 -0.685397  0.845976  w  0.75
1  0.065439  2.642052  x  0.50
2 -0.220823 -2.040816  y  0.33
3 -1.331632 -0.162705  z  0.25
```

I've tried using `lambdas`, `pandas.applymap`, `pandas.map`, etc but cannot seem to crack this one. So for those that will point out I have not actually asked a question, how would I map `tp` do `df` such that the the second element in each tuple lands in a new column that corresponds with the row matching the first element in each tuple?

Comment: I suspect the problem you were having with `map` is that it takes a function or a dict. There are many places where a list of 2-tuples can be used in place of a dict, but this isn't one of them; `map` will try to treat that list as a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn your list of tuples into a dict which is ridiculously easy to do in python, then call `map` on it:

```
In [4]:

df['new'] = df['c'].map(dict(tp))
df
Out[4]:
              a         b  c   new
index                             
0     -0.685397  0.845976  w  0.75
1      0.065439  2.642052  x  0.50
2     -0.220823 -2.040816  y  0.33
3     -1.331632 -0.162705  z  0.25
```

The docs for [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) show that that it takes as a function arg a dict, series or function.

[`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap) takes a function as an arg but operates element wise on the whole dataframe which is not what you want to do in this case.

The [online docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#applying-elementwise-python-functions) show how to apply an operation element wise, as does the excellent [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do)

Answer (score -1):

Does this example help?

```
class pandas.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)

>>> d = {'col1': ts1, 'col2': ts2}
>>> df = DataFrame(data=d, index=index)
>>> df2 = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5))
>>> df3 = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5),
... columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```